# Malicious actors in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I've been looking a bit on hyperleger fabric, and I saw that it uses a CFT consensus.

I'm wondering, what happens when I have a malicious actor on the network?
How dos fabric deals with malicious actors?

Answer (score 0):

@Oninik

At present hyperledger fabric supports

- solo
- kafka
- raft

All these three consensus mechanisms don't support/ handle Malicious actors

As PBFT will support and it is not yet part of fabric

**Note**: solo is just one orderer, kafka and raft can handle fault tolerance but not  Malicious actors.

Comment: I meant something more like, since the consensus is CFT and doesn't handle malicious actors, how does fabric as a whole handle them in general if there is one?